# divide Image to equal image size and set them as pane Background

Tags: java, image, javafx-8

Using JAVA Fx

can not use the javax.awt image , so how to use it, without writing to filethen retrive it and loop the process

```
    private class Tile extends StackPane {

        public Tile(double rectangularDimension, Image imgAWT) {

            Rectangle border = new Rectangle(rectangularDimension, rectangularDimension);
            border.setFill(null);
            border.setStroke(Color.BLACK);


            Image image = new Image(imgAWT, rectangularDimension, rectangularDimension, false, true, true);
            BackgroundImage myBI= new BackgroundImage(new Image("fd",this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),false,true),
                    BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,
                    BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);
            //then you set to your node
            this.setBackground(new Background(myBI));

            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            getChildren().addAll(border);

            setOnMouseClicked(this::handleMouseClick);
        }
    }
```

I Divided the images using Sub Image
then Scaled it to fit the tiles, I do not know how to set it as background, if i convert it to image view then add to tile as node(only dots are appeared)
so i need to it as background so i can stretch it

```
private Parent createContent() throws IOException {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.setPrefSize(ROOT_SIZE, ROOT_SIZE);

    String imagePath = "D:\\secret.jpg";
    BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));

    int w = image.getWidth();
    int h = image.getHeight();

    board = new Tile[SPAN][SPAN];
    for (int i = 0; i < SPAN; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SPAN; j++) {

            BufferedImage wim=image.getSubimage(i*w/SPAN,j*h/SPAN, w/SPAN, h/SPAN);
            Image sc=wim.getScaledInstance((ROOT_SIZE/SPAN)/SPAN,
                    (ROOT_SIZE/SPAN)/SPAN, Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING);

            Tile tile = new Tile(ROOT_SIZE/SPAN, sc);
            tile.setTranslateX(j * ROOT_SIZE/SPAN);
            tile.setTranslateY(i * ROOT_SIZE/SPAN);

            root.getChildren().addAll(tile);

            board[j][i] = tile;
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Load the initial image directly as a `javafx.scene.image.Image` from the file. Then you can just create multiple `ImageView`s from the same image, and set their viewports differently, if I understand your question. I'm not really clear on what your code is trying to do... doesn't it just break an image into tiles and then reassemble it?

Comment: I am trying to make a graphical password app like [here](https://techyrajeev.blogspot.com.eg/2012/08/java-program-to-divide-image-into.html) using JAVA fx and without buttons